# Kusto UDF syntax error if used in table expression but not in print

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a computational mystery[tm].
Consider this UDF:

```
let getdomain = (x: string) {
        toscalar(suffixes|where suf contains x|limit 1)
}
```

If I use it as: `print(getdomain("something"))` it works as expected

If I use it as: `MyTable | extend domain=getdomain(MyTableColumn1)` it throws a syntax error

If I make a change to the UDF as follows, then the table expression suddenly works:

```
let getdomain = (x: string) {
        toscalar(suffixes|where suf contains "staticstring"|limit 1)
}
```

if it matters, suffixes is an externaldata table of strings

EDIT: I came up with this monstrosity to overcome with my inability to do this dynamically, my suffixes have no more than 5 segments:

```
| extend 
 seg1=extract(@"(\w+$)",1,hostname),
 seg2=extract(@"([^.]+\.\w+$)",1,hostname),
 seg3=extract(@"([^.]+\.[^.]+\.\w+$)",1,hostname),
 seg4=extract(@"([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.\w+$)",1,hostname),
 seg5=extract(@"([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.\w+$)",1,hostname)
|extend 
 seg1match=seg1 in (suffixes),
 seg2match=seg2 in (suffixes),
 seg3match=seg3 in (suffixes),
 seg4match=seg4 in (suffixes),
 seg5match=seg5 in (suffixes)
|extend domain=coalesce(
 iff(seg5match, extract(@"([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.\w+$)",1,hostname),""),
 iff(seg4match, seg5,"" ),
 iff(seg3match, seg4,""),
 iff(seg2match, seg3, ""),
 iff(seg1match, seg2,""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think you're seeing a *syntax* error.

rather you're encountering [restrictions on user defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#restrictions-user-defined-functions-usage):

> User-defined functions can't pass into `toscalar()` invocation information that depends on the row-context in which the function is called.

Comment: What would you suggest I do instead? the suffixes table is essentially a lookup - i find longest suffix and return that. The toscalar attempts to fetch that first value // cc @yoni-l